# Remove Element Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, show-hide

I have a Literal and inside it some Google analytic scripts. I want to remove the Literal from source of the page on load but then reattach it later on a dropdown index change.

say my Literal is this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrGoogle" runat="server">
<script>
</script>
</asp:Literal>
```

I have tried jquery's `detach()`, `show()/hide()`, `attr` but when I see the source I can still see the script.

The only way to remove it completely is in code behind by setting the `visible = false`on `load` event, but then I cannot set it back to true in jquery on dropdown selected index change event, as it is removed from DOM.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What's inside the script tag? Is it just JS functions? If so, why not just call them if/when required? Possibly using eval()?

Comment: What are you doing to view the source? If you're using "View Source", it will always show the page as it was loaded from the server. You need to use the developer tools (usually accessible in browsers by pressing F12 on Windows) to see changes in your DOM.

Comment: @Blade0rz it is Google scripts for analytic...what you mean by eval()?

Comment: Have you tried .empty() of jquery.

Comment: I'd like to highlight Charlie Kilian's comment that the view-source of the page in all browsers will stay the same no matter what happens. Viewing the source of the page is like viewing the source of a class, when it runs the source code stays the same but the state of the object changes. In your case you want to see the state of the DOM, which can be done in FireFox using firebug or Chrome using inspect-element or IE > 9 by pressing F12. Those are the equivalent of debuggers for webpages. (No analogy is perfect, and apologies if you already knew that basic fact).

Comment: @welegan thanks for reply I just found out about this you are right the source of page doesnt get refreshed at all. I can see my change only in firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing and adding `script` on `select` index change, you can add `script` through `html()` on select index change.

```
$('#selectId').change(function(){
    $('<%=ltrGoogle.ClientID %>').html("<script><\/script>");
});
```

OR, put the script on seprate js file and dynamically add script.

```
$('#selectId').change(function(){
    var script = document.createElement( "script" );
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "scriptname.js";
    $("<%=ltrGoogle.ClientID %>").append(script);
});
```

Or, you can try load whole page, using jQuery load

```
$('#selectId').change(function(){      
    $("<%=ltrGoogle.ClientID %>").load("urlOfHtmlContainGoogleScriptOrHtml");
});
```

Comment: If I put it in separate file can I hide it in code behind, say on load event?

Comment: ltrGoogle.Visible = false.

Comment: Oh I see you mean have the ltrGoogle there hide it in load event, then use second option to load from file?

Comment: No, you should not add script ltrGoogle as you did, but dynamically add it.

Comment: <asp:Literal ID="ltrGoogle" runat="server">
<script>
</script>
</asp:Literal> would be <asp:Literal ID="ltrGoogle" runat="server">
</asp:Literal>

Comment: ok i get it but what if i have several scripts e.g. <asp:Literal ID="ltrGoogle" runat="server"> <script> </script> <script src="https://www.googleadservices.com/conversion.js"> </script> </asp:Literal>

Comment: also when i do this  $('<%=ltrGoogle.ClientID %>').html("<script></script>"); I get error : 
Error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
Source Code:$('ltrGoogle').html("<script>

Comment: You have to escape the forward slash of closing script tag, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/5LydD/

Comment: Ok now I don't get the error but it doesn't add it to literal when checking it through firebug I get a span <span id="ltrGoogle"></span> instead of literal. Also I like the second option, is there a way to load the whole file instead of adding type to it....

Comment: hmmm still same doesnt load and html doesnt work is it because it is translated to span?

Comment: you wont get in source page, try putting simple alert and check if it works ? some times code like google analytic might not execute due to some constraint.